# Рассцветка кода VS code javascript. Подскажите удобные расширения

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, расширения

Подскажите, может знает кто интересное расширение на Visual Code для javascript. Много перепробовал, но чтоб конкретно в "скобках" была раскраска, так и не нашел. 2 картинке, как удобно это смотрится на Веб-шторме и как неудобно на ВС-коде.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это называется темой, выбирайте какая понравится [https://vscodethemes.com/](https://vscodethemes.com/)